# Refraining from adding Data layer reference to the UI layer project, with MVC Core and EF Core

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, n-tier-architecture

I have created a project structure like below (using **ASP.NET Core**)

- MyProject

  - MyProject.Data
  - MyProject.Business
  - MyProject.Web
  - ...

In this, *Business* project references the *Data* project and *Web* project references the *Business* project. Then I have added the **Entity Framework Core** library to Data project and created a `Database Context` class.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public SlcDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> option)
        : base(option)
    {}

    public DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; }

}
```

Now I'm trying to register `MyDbContext` with ASP.NET Core built in Dependency Injection Service, for that I need to add below code to `Startup.cs` in the *Web* project

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            ...
}
```

but this code requires reference to `EntityFramework Core` library and *Data* project.

Is there any way to deal with this without adding the unnecessary references to the *Web* project (as UI layer should be independent from the Data layer)?

Comment: Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/300376/does-having-di-happen-in-the-composition-root-go-against-the-whole-point-of-depe

Comment: *Your UI code* should be independent of the data layer. A reference can exist, and you can code your UI so that you do not use it. *The composition root* **has** to use it, otherwise your composition root cannot register the correct interface with the correct data-layer-implementation.